# How can i sort this list by "date modified"?

Tags: php

I have been trying to get this mp3 player to order the songs by " date modified" but just can't seem to get this to work properly. Is there a way that i can output the results by " date modified"? Can anyone help me out with this?

```
    /*  Reads mp3's from a local 
directory, returns array of uri's */            
function grab_local_folder_mp3s( $folder ) {
    $items = array_multisort(

              array_map( 'filemtime', $items ),
              SORT_NUMERIC,
              SORT_DESC,
              $items
              );
    if ( ($lp = strpos($folder, $this->Rooturl)) || preg_match("!^/!", $folder) ) {
        if ( $lp !== false ) {
            $fp = str_replace($this->Rooturl, "", $folder);
            $fp = str_replace("www.", "", $fp);
            $fp = str_replace("http://", "", $fp);
            $fp = str_replace("https://", "", $fp);
        } else {
            $fp = $folder;
        }
        $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $fp;
        if ($handle = @opendir($path)) {
            $j=0;
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ( $file != '.' && $file != '..' && filetype($path.'/'.$file) == 'file' && preg_match("!\.mp3$!i", $file) ) {
                    $items[$j++] = $file;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
            if ( ($c = count($items)) > 0 ) {
                asort($items);

                if ( $this->folder_order != "asc" ) {
                    $items = array_reverse($items, true);
                }
                $fp = preg_replace( "!/+$!", "", $fp );
                foreach ( $items as $i => $mp3 ) {
                    $items[$i] = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $fp . "/" . $mp3;
                }
            }
            $this->dbug['str'] .= "\nRead folder - Done, " . $c . "mp3(s) in folder http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $fp;
            return $items; //the tracks array
        } else {
            $this->dbug['str'] .= "\nRead folder - Couldn't open local folder, check path/permissions to http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $fp;
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        $this->dbug['str'] .= "\nRead folder - Path was remote or unreadable." . $fp;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have special powers, the `$items` variable remains undefined:

```
function grab_local_folder_mp3s( $folder ) {
    $items = array_multisort(

              array_map( 'filemtime', $items ),
              SORT_NUMERIC,
              SORT_DESC,
              $items
              );
```

And that is only the beginning of your function. Maybe it's worth to think about how to split your code across more than one function? A good rule of saying is: six lines in a function. If it gets longer, start to think about how to move code out of it. Try it, it works wonder.

And also for development: Enable error reporting to the highest level and trace the error log. PHP tells you about such mistakes and you know where to look quite fast then. Also keep PHP updated to get the best error messages available.